# hide table rows based on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, hide

I have a HTML table filled with events. Each event has a date. The table rows look like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Event</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
      <tr data-date="2017-03-27">
        <td>2017-03-27</td>
        <td>My event detail</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-date="2017-03-28">
        <td>2017-03-28</td>
        <td>My event detail 2</td>
      </tr>                  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Based on the current date I want to hide all rows/events that are older than current date. I'm thinking this could be achieved using a jQuery function that runs when the page loads. Can anyone show me how I could do this?

Comment: Please add _to the question_ what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far nothing at all since I'm not that familiar with jquery and could need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.event_display_table tbody tr').each(function(index, element) {
        event_day = $(this).attr('data-date');
  event_day = new Date(event_day);
  //today = new Date('2017-03-14');
  today = new Date();
  if(event_day.getTime() < today.getTime())
  { 
     $(this).css('display','none');
  }
  
  console.log($(this).attr('data-date'));
  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="event_display_table"  border="1" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Event</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr data-date="2017-03-13">
                <td>2017-03-13</td>
                <td>My event detail 2</td>
              </tr>                  
                <tr data-date="2017-03-15">
                <td>2017-03-15</td>
                <td>My event detail 2</td>
              </tr>                  

              <tr data-date="2017-03-27">
                <td>2017-03-27</td>
                <td>My event detail</td>
              </tr>

              <tr data-date="2017-03-28">
                <td>2017-03-28</td>
                <td>My event detail 2</td>
              </tr>                  

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! This work exactly as I wanted it

Answer (score 0):

I've placed working code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/niklakhani/pen/Mprqjx?editors=1011). I hope it will be helpful for you!

```
(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var curDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;

  var curRow = $('tr[data-date="' + curDate + '"]').index();
  var rows = $('tr[data-date]').length;

  for (curRow - 1; curRow <= rows; curRow++) {
    $('tr[data-date]:eq(' + curRow + ')').css('display', 'none');
  }
})();
```